# Convert long lat tuple into linestring

Tags: line, geopandas

I have a dataframe of long/lat tuples and am trying to convert it into a Linestring that I can use in a Geopandas dataframe. The current format is [(-105.279, 40.060), (-105.279, 40.058), (-105.282, 40.058), (-105.282, 40.058), (-105.282, 40.03)] etc. Is there a library or technique to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you are looking for shapely:

https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#LineString

```py
import geopandas
from shapely.geometry import LineString

geom = LineString([(-105.279, 40.060), (-105.279, 40.058), (-105.282, 40.058), (-105.282, 40.058), (-105.282, 40.03)])

gdf = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(geometry=[geom])
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to do this as a geom = LineString(df[column])?

Comment: Mind opening a new one with the details of your problem?